# How could I get regex to start when it has reached a specific point within a string?

Tags: python, regex, string

Say I have a string like `{{ComputersRule}}` and a regex like: `[^\}]+`. How would I get regular expressions to start at a specified point in the string, i.e. Once it has reached the third character in the string. If it's relevant, and I doubt it is, I'm working in Python version 2.7.3. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using Python to grab the substring from the third character onwards, and then apply the regex to the rest.

Otherwise, you could just use the regex `.` (any character except newline) to gobble up the first `n` characters:

```
^.{3}([^\}]+)
```

Notice the `^.{3}` which forces the `[^\}]+` to not include the first three characters of the string (the `^` anchors to the start of the string/line). The brackets capture the bit you want to extract (so get capturing group 1).

In your *particular* case, if it's just a case of "I want the text inside the `{{` and `}}`" you could do `\{\{([^\}]+)\}\}` or `[^\{\}]+`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you want to do is to match text within the double braces.

The trick is to specify the braces in the regex but *capture* the part within.  In this case try

```
\{\{([^}]+)\}\}
```